# Is the "browser cookies" the same as HTTP cookies

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

Just to be clear and not playing with words, the term "browser cookies", is the same as the HTTP cookies. Or is there a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Browser cookie is just another way of saying HTTP cookie and vise versa.

You have two types of cookies one that stay even when you close your browser and another that disappear when you close your browser. look up Session cookies and persistent cookies.